# This is part of a code to auto-fill a web-page in google chrome (using console), What programming language is it?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

I'm trying to understand this code to auto-fill a webpage, what is the language?

```
$('body').append('<script>' +
'function autoFill() {' +
'   $("input[data-colorid=\'81\']").prop("checked", true);' +
'   $("input[data-colorid=\'81\']").trigger("click");' +
'  $("input[name=\'GoldenCard\']").filter(\':first\').prop("checked", true);' +
'  $("input[name=\'GoldenCard\']").filter(\':first\').trigger("click");' +

'   $("#featuresNextStep").trigger("click");' +

'   $("input[name=firstName]").val("some name").trigger("change");' +              


'   $("#directiveProvince").val("5").trigger("change");' +  
'   $("#directiveCity").val("227").trigger("change");' +                      
'   $("#LoginButton").trigger("click");'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's jQuery.

`$` is an alias for `jQuery`, and after `$` follows the element selecting query.

Example:
`$("#LoginButton")` is the same like `getElementById("LoginButton")`.

Example 2:
`$("#LoginButton").trigger("click");` triggers a click event on the login button element in the DOM.